# "The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 7.4.0) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 7.4.0-alpha05 !:&é"'(qàçxxc;":

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

when i try to open a project

i get this error in my android studio projct :

The project is using an incompatible version (AGP 7.4.0) of the Android Gradle plugin. Latest supported version is AGP 7.4.0-alpha05

Where exactly is the error

Comment: `7.4.0` is actually _later_ than `7.4.0-alpha05` because release versions always come _after_ alpha/beta/preview versions.

Answer (score 0):

2/3 of your question is your answer twice.
Depending on point of view, either your Android Studio is too old, or your Android Gradle plugin is too new.
A release version (7.4.0) is of course newer than a pre-release version (7.4.0-alpha05).